# How to update value of nested jsonb attribute in postgresql db

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

```
{
"personalDetails": {
    "First Name": "Paul", 
    "Last Name": "Jamessen", 
    "Work Class": "A+", 
    "Working Unit": "Management", 
    "email": "demo@demo.com"
    }
}
```

I want to update the records whose Working Unit is Management to Work Class A, like below

```
{
"personalDetails": {
    "First Name": "Paul", 
    "Last Name": "Jamessen", 
    "Work Class": "A", 
    "Working Unit": "Management", 
    "email": "demo@demo.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like a very specific scenario that's unlikely to be helpful to others. The fact that you answered it yourself so quickly suggests it's a bit redundant on a Q&A site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
update table_name 
set column_name = jsonb_set("column_name", '{"personalDetails", "Work Class"}', '"A"'::jsonb) 
where column_name::json->'personalDetail'->>'Working Unit' = 'Management' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_set()`

```
update the_table
  set the_column = jsonb_set(the_column, '{personalDetails,"Work Class"}', '"A"')
where the_column #>> '{personalDetails,"Working Unit"}' = 'Management';
```

Comment: update table_name set column_name = jsonb_set("column_name", '{"personalDetails", "Work Class"}', '"A"'::jsonb) where column_name::json->'personalDetail'->>'Working Unit' = 'Management'

Thanks for the response but,above query worked for me.